# jenkins fails to install 2.89.4-1.1 version on Centos 7.4

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install jenkins 2.89.4-1.1 version of jenkins on a Centos 7.4 server but my installation fails with the below error,
j

```
enkins-2.89.4-1.1.noarch.rpm  FAILED
http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins-2.89.4-1.1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found        0% [                                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.



Error downloading packages:
  jenkins-2.89.4-1.1.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

The steps that i have tried so far

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum install jenkins-2.89.4-1.1
```

Can anyone suggest what to do next.
i looked out for the solutions in the website mentioned in the error but they dont seem to work

Answer (score 4):

I am facing similar kind of error, the simplest solution is

```
# yum clean all
# rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

OR

You can download the rpm manually

```
wget http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.89.4-1.1.noarch.rpm


rpm -ivh jenkins-2.89.4-1.1.noarch.rpm
```

The main cause of this issue: Due to the corruption of the local machine cache, try to clear cache on the system